# I need help to smooth a part with a bevel

Tags: modeling

[image]

It's my first time using Blender and I'm not that good, however I'm doing pretty well. I make FNAF meshes and I made a bevel on this part, and when I try to smooth the surface it makes these weird markings you see in the image

I try my hardest to try to fix this and nothing is working. Now you may ask why  I want to smooth this part, and that is I am exporting this Blender project, and in the the program I'm gonna import it in, there is a limit of polygons, so I obviously need to smooth this one part.

[image]

[image: Here are the markings]

[image: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIzUa.png]

Comment: hard to understand what your mesh looks like and what you're trying to achieve, please show more screenshots, give more details, maybe share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Definitely need more screenshots

Comment: I'm really just trying to smoothen out the face with the marks you see, and I'm just trying since im new i don't know much, just help me smoothen the markings on the face and not on the back.

Comment: There made a download link

Comment: what do you mean by whole loop?

Comment: I don't understand please give me a download link

Comment: You can use the smooth tool, just select the area what you want to smoothen and click on the vertex menu and select Smooth vertices.

Comment: Exactly i tried that and the part got those marks, i smoothed the faces and that exactly happened, can you help me?

Comment: I even tried smoothing out the vertices and nothing happened its not the vertices i want to smooth its the faces so i don't those markings , maybe your misunderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some duplicated loops overlapping other ones.

Select them using Select Edge Loops and dissolve them.

Image below:

[image]

Comment: thank you it worked but there are still a little bit of markings